# How to compare and match documents names with 2 datasets

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am trying to do a batch upload of PDFs. Their names are structured like this:

```
mm/yyyy AAA BBBB.pdf
```

- AAA is the 3 letter `PipeNameAbreviation`
- BBBB is the 3 or more letters/numbers `LocationAbbreviation`

In the plunker you will see the user will select the Company and Date in the view. They will then select the PDFs. What I need to do is compare the `PipeNameAbr` of the file with the `PipeNameAbr`'s in the database and then assign the correct `PipeId` & `PipeName` to the formdata. This will be a consistent number of letters, 3. I also need to the do the same thing with the `Location`, except I need the `LocationId` & `LocationAbr` for the formdata. The difference is the length of letters/numbers. So I need to compare and match with the last 4 of the `Abbreviation`.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dUVsJDDf0Esw6lxCQ5Uk?p=preview)

```
 var regex = /^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*)\..*$/i;
$scope.upload = function () {
    var files = $scope.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            if (regex.test(file.name)) { 
                var matches = file.name.match(regex);

                    $upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/apiBatchPipeLine',
                    fields: {

                        'typeId': 1,
                        'companyId': $scope.companyId.CompanyId,
                        'documentDate': $scope.model.documentDate,
                        'pipeId': $scope.PipeId,
                        'pipeName': $scope.PipeName,
                        'locationId': $scope.LocationId,
                        'locationAb': $scope.LocationAb
                    },
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                                JSON.stringify(data));
                }).error(function (err, result) {
                    console.log(err, result);
                });

            }

        }
    }
};
```

JSON

```
$scope.pipes = [{"$id":"1","PipeId":1,"PipeAb":"ANR","PipeName":"Transcanada ANR Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"2","PipeId":2,"PipeAb":"CGT","PipeName":"Columbia Gulf Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"3","PipeId":3,"PipeAb":"CHA","PipeName":"Enterprise Channel Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"4","PipeId":4,"PipeAb":"FGT","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Florida Gas Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"5","PipeId":5,"PipeAb":"GAB","PipeName":"Enbridge Garden Banks Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"6","PipeId":6,"PipeAb":"GLO ","PipeName":"American Midstream Gloria  Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"7","PipeId":7,"PipeAb":"GSO","PipeName":"Boardwalk Gulf South Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"8","PipeId":8,"PipeAb":"HIO","PipeName":"Enterprise High Island Offshore System","Documents":null},{"$id":"9","PipeId":9,"PipeAb":"HIP","PipeName":"American Midstream High Point Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"10","PipeId":10,"PipeAb":"HPL","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Houston Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"11","PipeId":11,"PipeAb":"TEJ","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tejas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"12","PipeId":12,"PipeAb":"KIN","PipeName":"Kinetica Partners Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"13","PipeId":13,"PipeAb":"NGP","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Natural Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"14","PipeId":14,"PipeAb":"SER","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Sea Robin Pipeline Company ","Documents":null},{"$id":"15","PipeId":15,"PipeAb":"SNT","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Southern Natural Gas Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"16","PipeId":16,"PipeAb":"SRY","PipeName":"MCPO Stingray Pipeline Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"17","PipeId":17,"PipeAb":"TGT","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tennessee Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"18","PipeId":18,"PipeAb":"TET","PipeName":"Spectra Energy Texas Eastern Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"19","PipeId":19,"PipeAb":"TXG","PipeName":"Boardwalk Texas Gas Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"20","PipeId":20,"PipeAb":"TSC","PipeName":"Williams Transcontinental Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"21","PipeId":21,"PipeAb":"TRK","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Trunkline Gas Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"22","PipeId":22,"PipeAb":"VGS","PipeName":"Targa Venice Gathering System","Documents":null}];
```

JSON

```
 $scope.locations = [{"$id":"1","LocationId":1,"LocationAb":"BS32","LocationName":"BravoSam 32","Documents":null},{"$id":"2","LocationId":2,"LocationAb":"MP46","LocationName":"MikePier 46","Documents":null},{"$id":"3","LocationId":3,"LocationAb":"MP140","LocationName":"MikePier 140","Documents":null},{"$id":"4","LocationId":4,"LocationAb":"VR16","LocationName":"VectorRoland 16","Documents":null},{"$id":"5","LocationId":5,"LocationAb":"AP96","LocationName":"AlphaPass 96","Documents":null},{"$id":"6","LocationId":6,"LocationAb":"DZ26","LocationName":"DeltaZulu 26","Documents":null},{"$id":"7","LocationId":7,"LocationAb":"SV963","LocationName":"SandmanViper 963","Documents":null}];
```

I am  attaching a screenshot of what I am currently looking at with what I have right now.
[image: Picture]

The PDFs I am using for testing are named

> 02-2015 HIP BS32.pdf
>
> 02-2015 HIP MP46.pdf
>
> 02-2015 HIP MP140.pdf
>
> 02-2015 TSC VR16.pdf

I have a regex that strips the date off the pdf name and separates the Pipe and Location. I believe I would need to loop through the file array but what kind of loop? Would I use a switch statement to compare? I created a plunker with the json from the db.

UPDATE here is the working angular version

```
$scope.upload = function () {
    var files = $scope.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            $scope.pipeLookup = {};
            $scope.locationLookup = {};
            
            $scope.pipes.map(function (pip) {
                $scope.pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
            });
            $scope.locations.map(function (loc) {
                $scope.locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
            });

            var matches = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);

                $scope.pipe = $scope.pipeLookup[matches[1]];
                $scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matches[2]];

                $upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/apiBatchPipeLine',
                    fields: {

                        'typeId': 1,
                        'companyId': $scope.companyId.CompanyId,
                        'documentDate': $scope.model.documentDate,
                        'pipeId': $scope.pipe.PipeId,
                        'pipeName': $scope.pipe['PipeName'],
                        'companyName': $scope.CompanyName,
                        'locationId': $scope.loc['LocationId'],
                        'locationAb': $scope.loc['LocationAb']
                    },
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    notificationFactory.success();
                }).error(function (err, result) {
                    notificationFactory.error();
                    console.log(err, result);
                });
            
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's unclear to me which "database" you wish to do the compare with. Is the data you wanna compare to pre-loaded? Or are you sending the filename to the server with an Ajax request for comparison there?

Comment: As well you speak of `LocationAbbreviation`, `LocationAbr` and `Abbreviation`. They sound like you mean the same thing thrice, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all the code from the plunker. The data will be preloaded. In the plunker you will see the $scope.locations and the $scope.pipes holds the data from the db

Comment: They r the same. Sorry for the inconsistency. Will change when I get to computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the abbreviations you have to match with will always be unique and you expect to do quite a bit of looking up. You could opt for iterating through the JSON once and storing the pipes/locations in a way that has the abbreviation as the key:

```
var pipeLookup = {};
var locationLookup = {};

$scope.pipes.map(function(pip) {
    pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
});
$scope.locations.map(function(loc) {
    locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
});
```

So here I'm saying that for every entry of `$scope.pipes`, I want an entry in `pipeLookup` with as `key` the pipe's `PipeAb` and as `value` the entire pipe object. After that, these `Lookup` variables are essentially hashmaps so you can easily find the correct pipe with the regex match capture groups like so:

```
var matches = file.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);
var pipe = pipeLookup[matches[1]];
var loc = locationLookup[matches[2]];
```

Then you have `pipe.PipeId`, `pipe.PipeName`, `loc.LocationId` and whatever other properties exist at your disposal to assign to the `fields` properties. *(Whether you wanna make these `pipeLookup` and `locationLookup` vars properties of `$scope` is up to you. I'm not terribly familiar with AngularJS)*

Find a stripped down version that demos matching the correct `Pipe`/`Location` properties for each filename in the code-snippet below. *(did it without AngularJS for simplicity)*

```js
var pipes = [{"$id":"1","PipeId":1,"PipeAb":"ANR","PipeName":"Transcanada ANR Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"2","PipeId":2,"PipeAb":"CGT","PipeName":"Columbia Gulf Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"3","PipeId":3,"PipeAb":"CHA","PipeName":"Enterprise Channel Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"4","PipeId":4,"PipeAb":"FGT","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Florida Gas Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"5","PipeId":5,"PipeAb":"GAB","PipeName":"Enbridge Garden Banks Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"6","PipeId":6,"PipeAb":"GLO ","PipeName":"American Midstream Gloria  Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"7","PipeId":7,"PipeAb":"GSO","PipeName":"Boardwalk Gulf South Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"8","PipeId":8,"PipeAb":"HIO","PipeName":"Enterprise High Island Offshore System","Documents":null},{"$id":"9","PipeId":9,"PipeAb":"HIP","PipeName":"American Midstream High Point Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"10","PipeId":10,"PipeAb":"HPL","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Houston Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"11","PipeId":11,"PipeAb":"TEJ","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tejas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"12","PipeId":12,"PipeAb":"KIN","PipeName":"Kinetica Partners Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"13","PipeId":13,"PipeAb":"NGP","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Natural Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"14","PipeId":14,"PipeAb":"SER","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Sea Robin Pipeline Company ","Documents":null},{"$id":"15","PipeId":15,"PipeAb":"SNT","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Southern Natural Gas Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"16","PipeId":16,"PipeAb":"SRY","PipeName":"MCPO Stingray Pipeline Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"17","PipeId":17,"PipeAb":"TGT","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tennessee Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"18","PipeId":18,"PipeAb":"TET","PipeName":"Spectra Energy Texas Eastern Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"19","PipeId":19,"PipeAb":"TXG","PipeName":"Boardwalk Texas Gas Transmission","Documents":null},{"$id":"20","PipeId":20,"PipeAb":"TSC","PipeName":"Williams Transcontinental Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},{"$id":"21","PipeId":21,"PipeAb":"TRK","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Trunkline Gas Company","Documents":null},{"$id":"22","PipeId":22,"PipeAb":"VGS","PipeName":"Targa Venice Gathering System","Documents":null}];
var locations = [{"$id":"1","LocationId":1,"LocationAb":"BS32","LocationName":"BravoSam 32","Documents":null},{"$id":"2","LocationId":2,"LocationAb":"MP46","LocationName":"MikePier 46","Documents":null},{"$id":"3","LocationId":3,"LocationAb":"MP140","LocationName":"MikePier 140","Documents":null},{"$id":"4","LocationId":4,"LocationAb":"VR16","LocationName":"VectorRoland 16","Documents":null},{"$id":"5","LocationId":5,"LocationAb":"AP96","LocationName":"AlphaPass 96","Documents":null},{"$id":"6","LocationId":6,"LocationAb":"DZ26","LocationName":"DeltaZulu 26","Documents":null},{"$id":"7","LocationId":7,"LocationAb":"SV963","LocationName":"SandmanViper 963","Documents":null}];

var files = ['02-2015 HIP BS32.pdf', '02-2015 HIP MP46.pdf', '02-2015 HIP MP140.pdf', '02-2015 TSC VR16.pdf'];

var pipeLookup = {};
var locationLookup = {};

pipes.map(function(pip) {
  pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
});
locations.map(function(loc) {
  locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
});

document.getElementById('out').value = files.map(function(file) {
  var matches = file.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);
  var pipe = pipeLookup[matches[1]];
  var loc = locationLookup[matches[2]];
  return file + '\tPipeId: ' + pipe['PipeId'] +
            '\tLocationId: ' + loc['LocationId'] + 
            '\tPipeName: ' + pipe['PipeName'];
}).join('\n');
```

```html
<textarea id="out" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

The alternative is to iterate through `$scope.pipes` and `$scope.locations` for every file. Which means less readable code and diminished performance.

Comment: looks good, i am trying to plug it in right now. ill get back with you asap

Comment: im going to open up another thread for the angular integration. thanks for getting me to the next step!