# how to get past type error inside angular-ui-upload function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to upload multiple documents. I am trying to do a match the two parts of the file name with the properties from a data set. I received help with this from another post, however the answer was in jquery and I am trying to implement it with my angular. I am stuck with this error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

at this line

```
var matches = file.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);
```

I tried wrapping it in a function `(function () {}` and it did remove the error but it did not do anything as far as it working. There where no errors either.

here is a link to the jquery solution
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159095/how-to-compare-and-match-documents-names-with-2-datasets)

and here is what i am currently working with.

```
  $scope.locations = Location.query(function () { });
$scope.pipes = Pipe.query(function () { });


$scope.upload = function () {
    var files = $scope.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            $scope.pipeLookup = {};
            $scope.locationLookup = {};

            $scope.pipes.map(function (pip) {
                $scope.pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
            });
            $scope.locations.map(function (loc) {
                $scope.locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
            });

            var matches = file.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);

                $scope.pipe = $scope.pipeLookup[matches[1]];
                $scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matches[2]];

                $upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/apiBatchPipeLine',
                    fields: {

                        'typeId': 1,
                        'companyId': $scope.companyId.CompanyId,
                        'documentDate': $scope.model.documentDate,
                        'pipeId': $scope.pipe['PipeId'],
                        'pipeName': $scope.pipe['PipeName'],
                        'locationId': $scope.loc['LocationId'],
                        'locationAb': $scope.loc['LocationAb']
                    },
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                                JSON.stringify(data));
                }).error(function (err, result) {
                    console.log(err, result);
                });

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You've placed my solution (with the `map(function(){...})` _inside_ the `for`-loop that iterates through the files. This will build up the `Lookup` vars again and again. I would place that code right after the `$scope.pipes = Pipe.query(function () { });`. That way you retrieve the data, map it in a way that makes it easily accessible only once, and then iterate through the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're calling at that line is [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which is a String method. Here, however, it is `undefined`. Is it possible that `file` is an object and not a string? If that's the case, you likely meant to do `file.name.match(...)`.